# file:///android_res/drawable not working when using flavor with other package name

Tags: android, gradle, android-webview, android-productflavors

My problem is that after I added flavors to my project the flavor with a package name different from the actual source seems to have problems with accessing the files in    `android_res/drawable`.

More specifically I have a html-view that calls the following image.

```
<img src="file:///android_res/drawable/image.png">
```

The image shows up in the production flavor that has the package name which is the same as the directory of the java-files but it doesn't work for the beta flavor:

```
productFlavors {
    production {
        packageName "com.company.myapp"
    }

    beta {
        packageName "com.company.beta"
    }
}
```

where the actual directory with the java files is

```
java/com/company/myapp
```

It is rather strange that this happens since the resources are not even in that folder.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I am struggling with the same problem.

Comment: Anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: Same problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29876363/android-studio-project-flavors-resources

Answer (score 4):

packageName is not supported in gradle. Gradle has a distinction between applicationId and packageName (see http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename) which means that should be able to have the resources package name differ from the package identifier for your application.

Unfortunately that does not seem to be supported by the file:///android_res URL scheme in a webview.

I was able to workaround it in my case by creating an R class in the other package with the correct inner class and with a public static final int field that was initialized with the value from the real R file. This is a hack and doesn't survive renaming the resource and is not convenient if you have lots of resources you need to access.

So in your case that would look like adding this to your beta flavor source files directory:

```
package com.company.beta;

class R
{
    class drawable
    {
        public static final int image = com.company.myapp.R.drawable.image;
    }
}
```

Comment: Abandoned this project a while ago so I can't test it right now. But if people start upvoting this answer I'll mark it as the correct one :)

Comment: What in the world. This is such a hack but it freakin' works! Upvoting. Too bad you have to fight the framework!

Comment: Very dirty yet viable. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

Have you set up your flavor folders properly?

If you have two flavors (flavorOne, flavorTwo) you need to set up the source folders accordingly.

Your build.gradle file should look something like this:

```
productFlavors {
        flavorOne {
            applicationId "com.package.name"
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        flavorTwo {
            applicationId "com.package.name.two"
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
}
```

So, here is what the folder structure would look like for those two flavors:

```
src
---|main
--------|java
-------------|com.package.name
--------|res
-------------|drawable

---|flavorOne
--------|java
-------------|com.package.name
--------|res
-------------|drawable

---|flavorTwo
--------|java
-------------|com.package.name
--------|res
-------------|drawable
```

Put the drawables for each flavor in it's associated folder.
So you would have the `image.png` file for `flavorOne` in that drawable folder and the `image.png` for `flavorTwo` in the `flavorTwo` drawable folder.

This way localization will work for each flavor.

You should NOT be creating 'R' classes. These are autogenerated.

**OLD ANSWER**

Not really a solution to your exact problem but another approach.

You could move your image files to the assets folder instead and use this

```
<img src="file:///android_asset/image.png">
```

Comment: Only a viable option if you don't care about localization of the item you are referencing which you get with resources.