# Android Studio project flavors resources

Tags: android

I created project flavors all right, and Android Studio installs 2 different applications to my device, that's ok.

However, I am trying to add an image from the drawable in HTML

```
<img src="file:///android_res/drawable/test.png" >
```

And this does not anymore work in the flavors. In the original project without flavors, it worked.

Is there something I must do for the resources to be included in the project flavors as well?

Comment: Can you add your project structure here? Where do you have your resources placed? Under `main` directory?

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused by different factor than adding flavours.

On which version of Android do you run your code? There has been changes to WebView starting KitKat (4.4), and it seems that it does not accept local assets/res anymore.

Please look at the logs and search for something like this:

> chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_res/drawable/test.png", source: data:text/html, (0)

Ticket from AOSP tracker: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63033

Please also run your application on pre-4.4 device or emulator to check whether image is rendered properly.

Comment: This works for the main flavour however. Also, it is tested on 4.2 as well.

Comment: Ok, looking further into this