# Use custom font from res/font with WebView in Android

Tags: android, webview, fonts, font-face, custom-font

I want to change font face of html string loaded into WebView similarly as mentioned in this question:

[How to change font face of Webview in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900658/how-to-change-font-face-of-webview-in-android)

The difference is that I am not using old approach where you store you font files in assets folder, but I store them in res/font as described in "Fonts in XML" android font support documentation:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html

Now, I obviously can't use:

`file:///android_asset/fonts/my_font.otf`

I tried:

`file:///android_res/font/my_font.otf`

and many other ways of describing path to my font inside of res/font folder, but none of them work.

How to use custom font family for a WebView that loads html string if my font is stored in res/font folder ?

//Edit:

My current implementation that is not working is:

```
@BindingAdapter("loadData")
public static void loadData(WebView webView, String htmlData) {
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlData, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
}

@BindingAdapter({"loadData", "fontFamily"})
public static void loadData(WebView webView, String htmlData, @FontRes int fontFamilyId) {
    TypedValue value = new TypedValue();
    ApplicationActivity.getSharedApplication().getResources().getValue(fontFamilyId, value, true);
    String fontPath = value.string.toString();
    File fontFile = new File(fontPath);

    String prefix = "<html>\n"
            +"\t<head>\n"
            +"\t\t<style type=\"text/css\">\n"
            +"\t\t\t@font-face {\n"
            +"\t\t\t\tfont-family: 'CustomFont';\n"
            +"\t\t\t\tsrc: url(\"file:///android_res/font/"+fontFile.getName()+"\")\n"
            +"\t\t\t}\n"
            +"\t\t\tbody {\n"
            +"\t\t\t\tfont-family: 'CustomFont';\n"
            +"\t\t\t}\n"
            +"\t\t</style>\n"
            +"\t</head>\n"
            +"\t<body>\n";
    String postfix = "\t</body>\n</html>";

    loadData(webView, prefix + htmlData + postfix);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change font face of Webview in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900658/how-to-change-font-face-of-webview-in-android)

Comment: It's not duplicate. I mentioned that topic - it describes loading fonts from assets folder, I am talking about loading font from res folder and new android font support.

Comment: Why don't change font by css?

Comment: @Steven isn't that what I am trying to do ? I am using css to change the font, I just don't know how to set the path to the font in res/font folder.

Comment: I mean why do It like that. When you just can create a css file and change the style in their?

Comment: Good Question, especially regarding the new possibility of Android Studio 3 to support fonts to be added directly via res/font folder.

Answer (score 19):

Just tried and this works similarly to loading fonts from assets, you just need to change the base url to point to resources instead.

Example HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'CustomFont';
            src: url('font/CustomFont.ttf');
        }
        #font {
            font-family: 'CustomFont';
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>No Font</p>
    <br />
    <p id="font">Font</p>
</body>
```

load this HTML into the webview using `Webview#loadDataWithBaseURL(String, String, String, String, String)`, using `file://android_res/` as the base url (first param)

Example:

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_res/", html, "text/html", "utf-8", null)
```

Edit:

If you're using proguard on your release builds you'll need to add extra rules to prevent the `R` class being renamed during the ProGuard process otherwise the WebView won't be able to find the font resource. Details can be found at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280188/prevent-proguard-to-remove-specific-drawables?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Hi, does this really work? I try it but webview logs exception "Unable to open resource URL: file:///android_res/font/ubuntu_regular.ttf" "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.xxx.yyy.zzz.R$font" on path:"

Comment: @PetrDaňa just came across this issue myself, seems to only be an issue with proguarded builds caused by the fact that proguard is renaming the `R` resources file and the webview therefore cannot find it. Solution is to use the proguard rules listed on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280188/prevent-proguard-to-remove-specific-drawables?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: does not work for me: `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` in the WebViews Console

Comment: For those who have an exception like `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "your.package.name.R$font"`. The cause may be that you have different applicationId's for debug/release or flavored builds.  You may find the explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23469712/file-android-res-drawable-not-working-when-using-flavor-with-other-package-na

Comment: Even added package in proguard file but still, it's not working.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me either.

Answer (score 13):

I managed to load my local font from `res/font` directory. In my example i want to load italic opensans.

My setup are as follow:

1. css file inside `assets` directory
2. use this for setting the font-face

```css
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'opensans';
      src: url("file:///android_res/font/opensans_italic.ttf")
    }

    body {
      font-family: 'opensans';
      font-weight: 400;
    }
```

3. Load the WebView using `loadDataWithBaseUrl`, for example:

   `webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, yourHtmlContent, "text/html", "utf-8", null)`

   But i have this at the the top of my html content:
   `"<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='file:///android_asset/mycss.css' />”`

   I hope it works too for your case.

Edit:

Add this in your proguard config to make it work in release mode.

`-keep class com.your.package.name.R$font { *; }`

Comment: worked for me, don't forget to create font folder in res by right clicking -> new -> Android Resource Directory. and also the name can only be in minuscule with _ and not -

Answer (score 3):

You can use the custom res font like this -

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    @font-face {
        font-family: MyFont;
        src: url("file:///res/font/myfont.ttf")
    }
    body {
        font-family: MyFont;
    }
</style>
```