# How to link font in css file present in android/assets folder from res/font directory

Tags: android, css, android-studio, fonts

i have added html and css file in assets folder of android project directory and i want a font to be loaded from new font support i.e. font/somefont.ttf

i have tried adding different ways but none worked like as explained here [Use custom font from res/font with WebView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46344725/use-custom-font-from-res-font-with-webview-in-android)

```
@font-face {
  font-family: jost;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: url("file:///android_res/font/jost_400_book.ttf");
}
```

it should give apply font but i get get this exception in console

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.turningpoint.turningpoint.staging.R$font"
```

and no font is loadded.

Comment: check your font folder

Comment: Are you putting the font there : app/assets/fonts?

Comment: my fonts are present in font folder @orbit

Answer (score 0):

check your font folder `android_res/font/` exist

```
src: url("file:///android_res/font/jost_400_book.ttf");
```

use this

```
src: url("file:///android_asset/fonts/MyFont.otf")
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have added and html and css file in assets folder of android project directory

But I'm not seeing that you are pointing `assets` folder, you are pointing `android_res` can you try this one? :

```
src: url('file:///android_asset/font/jost_400_book.ttf');
```

Comment: no i want to refer them from font folder present in res/font

Comment: @WaqarAfzal got any solution?